# Style only paragraphs that are inside a div using CSS

Tags: html, css

So I am currently trying to edit the "line-height" of my Wordpress paragraphs. The problem is that I have multiple p tags on my page, and I'm only interested in changing the paragraphs that are located inside a div named "entry-content", which is actually the article of the page.

Here is the basic code of the php page I have:

```
<div class="entry-content">
<p style="text-align: center;">Paragraph 1</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```

So my question is if there's a way to do something like that in css (so it only affects the paragraphs that are inside the div entry-content:

```
.entry-content {

p, li {
  line-height: 30px;
}
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector needs to be:

```css
div.entry-content p {
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

This will style all `<p>` elements that are descendants of a `<div>` element with the class name "entry-content".

Comment: Thanks, can it work with just ".entry-content p {" on the first line? or "div" has to be written as well? thanks

Comment: @Sylvia889p - If you remove the `div` prefix then it will match all `<p>` elements that are descendants of any element with the class name "entry-content". With CSS, it is important to be as specific as possible. If you know for a fact that you only want to style paragraphs that are in divs with the specific class name, then I would personally keep the `div` prefix.